# Telethon Get Update When Contact Join Telegram

Tags: telethon, telegram-api

I'm using [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) and i'm trying to implement a handler to listen events when a contact of mine joined to Telegram, but i don't find any documentation about that.

I see the docs of telethon updates events [Telethon Doc - Update Events](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html) but i don't find a way to filter this specific event. Right now Telegram send a push notification when any of your contact join telegram and create a chat, so i think there should be an event that marks this

Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to [`events.Raw`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.raw.Raw) and do a few checks on the `event` object that should look like [this](https://pastebin.com/80208S0y).

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import MessageActionContactSignUp, UpdateNewMessage

client = TelegramClient('YOUR_SESSION_NAME', 'YOUR_API_ID', 'YOUR_API_HASH')
client.start()

@events.register(events.Raw)
async def contact_join(event):
    if isinstance(event, UpdateNewMessage) and isinstance(event.message.action, MessageActionContactSignUp):
        print(event.message.from_id) #show the id of the contact joined

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
client.add_event_handler(check_join)
loop.run_forever()
```